# Automatic Image Re sizing

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site [here](http://elixdesigns.com/gisell/), to replicate the functionality of [Chanel's](http://www.chanel.com/) website.

Currently the re-sizing works width wise but when it comes to height I can't for the life of me get it to work correctly so that the image is centered and just a bit above the footer. All my images are 1920 x 1080 just as Chanel has. Also Chanels site if you scroll just a bit down it pulls the bottom half up automatically where as I only got it to work with just the button.

When I view the page on an iPad only about 75% of the site shows up. I thought it was do to the more buttons padding but that was not the issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also Chanels site if you scroll just a bit down it pulls the bottom
>   half up automatically where as I only got it to work with just the
>   button.

This is because the `div` at the top is fixed or absolute.  The "bottom half" probably has a top margin of 100% that only becomes visible on scroll.

It "pulls up automatically" via javascript; if you turn javascript off acts normally.  To do that, they probably use something like `document.body.onscroll = function() { ...animation... }`.

The CSS for the `div#languages.popin` (id = languages, class = popin) is as follows:

```
.popin {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 900px;
    height: 600px;
    margin-top: -300px;
    margin-left: -450px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255);
    z-index: 150;
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

I assume by following that, you'll get similar results.  Try out firebug, or a variant thereof, and inspect the elements to find parts you may have forgotten.